# PLS-DA prediction of a single row of data returns multiple predictions

Tags: r, prediction, r-caret, predict

I'm using the plsda function of the caret package to train a model on a dataset and am trying to use it to predict class participation of new datasets. However, when I try to predict a single row of the same dataset, predict() returns multiple results. I'm not sure what's going on here.

A minimal example is shown below

```
library(caret)

#Generate random dataset
trainLow <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = rnorm(533*32), nrow = 32, ncol = 533))
trainLowClass <- as.factor(rep(1:8, each = 4))

#Train model
low_plsda_model <- plsda(trainLow, 
                         trainLowClass,
                         probMethod = "Bayes",
                         ncomp = 4,
)
```

predict() works for datasets with more than 1 observation, but returns 7 predicted classes when newdata consists of just 1 observation

```
#Expected to return 32 predictions
> predict(low_plsda_model, trainLow, ncomp = 2)
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#Expected to return 2 predictions
> predict(low_plsda_model, trainLow[1:2,], ncomp = 2)
[1] 1 1
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

#Expected to return 1 prediction
> predict(low_plsda_model, trainLow[1,], ncomp = 2)
[1] 4 7 4 3 5 6 7
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Anybody have any idea what's going on? I'm quite a newbie at R.

Comment: Hi Aaron, Welcome to StackOverflow. At least you should say which package you are using to fit plsda.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I did mention that I was using the plsda function of the caret package. Let me edit my source to make it clearer